# Xcode - Button Highlight Inconsistency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button that I create in interface builder that highlights the entire button on tap. I do nothing in code, simply ctrl+drag to my view controller file.

[image]

Then I have another button that I create programatically with this code.

```
let goToButton = UIButton()
goToButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
goToButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)
goToButton.setTitle("◀︎ Go To Form", forState: .Normal)
goToButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
goToButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true // Should highlight entire button?
```

but on tap it look like this.

[image]

How can I make it so that it matches the highlight like a button from interface builder

Comment: check your button type

Comment: goToButton  = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) may work

Comment: Did you try not using showsTouchWhenHighlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your button type as `Custom` or `System and try once , change this

```
let goToButton = UIButton()
```

into

```
let goToButton = UIButton(type:.System)
```

or

```
let goToButton = UIButton(type:.Custom)
```

and hide this

```
 goToButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
```